# Compare algorithms by time{O(n logn) or O(kn)} and space{O(1) and O(k)} respectively

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, data-structures

If i have 2 algorithms A and B
Where A uses O(n logn) time and O(1) extra space.
On the other hand B uses O(nk) time and O(k-1) extra space.
What you guys think which one would be a better choice? And why?

Comment: I would use the one that performs better for the given problem I want to solve. Complexity cannot tell you that, it can only give you a first hint

Comment: Can you please tell me how would you figure it out on the basis of problem

Comment: `O(n logn)` can have `t = n * log(n)` *execution time* while the second algorithm `t = 1e100 * n`. So even if 2nd algorithm has a better *Big O*, the 1st one is faster for all reasonable input. Same for the space

Comment: If n is the problem size and k is a constant, O(kn) == O(n) and O(k-1) == O(1).  That said, @largest_prime_is_463035818 hit the nail on the head.  Bear in mind that O describes asymptotic behavior.

Comment: run benchmarks. If you want to get an estimate before actually writing code asymptotic complexity alone does not really help (for some given `n` and `k`), because it ignores constant factors

Comment: Okay, thanks to all for answering

Answer (score 1):

Better choice is the one which doesn't exceed memory budget and is measurably faster in production conditions. A reliable way to find that out is measuring.

If you're writing a library that will/may be used in many different environments, then a good choice is to implement both algorithms and let the user choose.